# linux locate command sort by date

Tags: linux, command-line, locate

The linux locate command is great at finding files quicky.

My question: how can we use the locate command so that the results are returned in date/time order?

Answer (score 7):

This works as long as there are not spaces in the filenames, but errors if there are too many files (see http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#Argument-list-too-long):

```
$ ls -td $(locate sh)
bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

This will work even with spaces or other characters in filenames, but doesn't sort correctly with too many files:

```
locate something -0 | xargs -0 ls -ltd
```

The following will always work (although it might take awhile):

```
locate something -0 | xargs -0 stat -c'%Y %n' | sort -n
```

Comment: Piping to `stat` was ten times faster than piping to `ls` for me, although it doesn't show all the `ls -l` information, obviously.

Comment: to show modification time in human readable format (works as long as there is no # character in the filename: 
`locate SomeSearchTerm -0 | xargs -0 stat -c'%Y#%y %n' | sort -n | cut -d"#" -f2 | sed "s/\.[0-9]*//"`

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
ls -td $(locate something)
```

or

```
ls -td1 $(locate something)
```

Comment: Maybe a `-d` would be handy, too.

Comment: @choroba: good point, I'll update the answer.

Comment: This fails for files with spaces in their name.